# MiniProfiler for AspNetCore MySql connection

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, logging, sql-server-profiler, miniprofiler

In .Net framework I use MiniProfiler for MySql connection command logging. In my current AspNetCore solution MiniProfiler doesn't show sql commands as well. What MiniProfiler options I should be using to log it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,
It is not for Entity Framework, but solution is using MiniProfiler to profile MySQL Server. And the connection is wrap as following:

```
public DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    DbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("...");
    return new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
}
```

But this does not help, as it does not capture actual SQL command with the parameter list. Please suggest if any additional options need to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework Core, you need to:

1. Install the [MiniProfiler.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EntityFrameworkCore) NuGet package.
2. In your `Startup.cs`, call `AddEntityFramework()`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMiniProfiler()
            .AddEntityFramework();
}
```

Source: [MiniProfiler documentation](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileEFCore)

Comment: I don't use EntityFramework. I need to log sql commands for MySqlConnection + Dapper